# Retaining value from textbox in an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

Here's my .h file:

The IBOutlet I am having problems with is the textbox. I would like to retain the value in the textbox as an NSString:

```
@interface UploaderViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textCaption;
    NSString *caption;
}

- (IBAction)pushPick;
- (IBAction)pushUpload;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textCaption;

@end
```

Where the value is stored in this NSString:

```
- (IBAction)pushUpload {
    caption = textCaption.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)pushUpload {
    [caption release];
    caption = [textCaption.text copy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In shouldChangeTextInRange call your pushUpload.